# series implication

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n \in\ \mathbb{N^*}}$ ,  $(b_n)_{n \in\  \mathbb{N^*}}$ a sequence of real numbers. Show that:

converges $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ and is $(b_n)_{n \in\  \mathbb{N^*}}$ bounded and monotone,  so converges $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$.
$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$

I've already proofed that, if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges absolutely and if $(b_n)_{n \in\  \mathbb{N^*}}$ is bounded, that then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nb_n$ converges absolutely.

My idea is, to use that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k$ $= A_nb_{n+1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}A_k(b_k-b_{k+1})$ is for $A_k=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k}a_j$  for $ 1  \leq k \leq n$   but i don't really know how to start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ and $N_0$ large enough that if $N > M \geq N_0$ then $\bigg|\sum_{n=M}^Na_n\bigg|<\epsilon$. Since $(b_n)$ is monotone and bounded, then $(b_n)$ is Cauchy and $\sum_{k=M}^N|b_{k}-b_{k-1}| = |b_N-b_M|$. Now

$$
\bigg| \sum_{n=M}^{N} a_n b_n \bigg| = \bigg| \sum_{n=M}^{N}\sum_{k=M}^n  a_n (b_k- b_{k-1})\bigg| \\
= \bigg| \sum_{k=M}^N \bigg\{ (b_k-b_{k-1}) \sum_{n=k}^N a_n \bigg\} \bigg| \leq \sum_{k=M}^N \bigg\{|b_k-b_{k-1}| \bigg| \sum_{n=k}^N a_n \bigg|\bigg\}\\
\leq |b_N-b_M|\epsilon
$$

You can now conclude that the sum meets the Cauchy criteria for convergence.